# How do i search for a text in a column and then use that column to print the entire row using gspread & python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

Here's the example of my code.

```
cell_list = wks.find(input_ID)
print("Text found at R%sC%s" % (cell_list.row, cell_list.col))
get_row = int(("%s" % (cell_list.row)))
print(get_row)
searched_row = wks.row_value(get_row)
print(searched_row)
```

The error I'm getting...

```
Text found at R5C5
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Users/Win81/Desktop/testing.py", line 18, in <module>
    searched_row = wks.row_value(get_row)
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'row_value'
```

I realize the problem is at the get_row. I've searched up online and all the examples are putting in a number in the bracket. However, how do I go about doing this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the line where you are trying to get the row values:

- Currently: `searched_row = wks.row_value(get_row)`
- Should be: `searched_row = wks.row_values(get_row)`

(Notice plural `row_values` ... *not* singular `row_value`)

When I make this correction, your code runs fine on an example that I set up to replicate your problem:

```
(BEFORE THE TYPO FIX)
> python gspread-fix.py
Text found at R5C5
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gspread-fix.py", line 20, in <module>
    searched_row = wks.row_value(get_row)
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'row_value'

(AFTER THE TYPO FIX)
>python gspread-fix.py
Text found at R5C5
5
['y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3']
```

For reference, here's a copy of the complete code with the typo fix and a snapshot of the Google Sheet that I used to test and verify the fix:

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account()

# Open a sheet from a spreadsheet in one go
wks = gc.open("gspread-test").sheet1

input_ID = '2'
# original
cell_list = wks.find(input_ID)
print("Text found at R%sC%s" % (cell_list.row, cell_list.col))
get_row = int(("%s" % (cell_list.row)))
print(get_row)
searched_row = wks.row_values(get_row)
print(searched_row)
```

[image]

For further reference, if others are interested in getting started with gspread, I found this quick authentication run-through very helpful:

- https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#enable-api-access

Comment: Oh my god, I can’t believe it actually worked! That single letter caused me hours of confusion of not knowing where did I go wrong. I’m laughing my heart out right now. Thank you so much for the guidance. There’s lots of improvement for me to do. Will definitely checkout the document you attached. Thanks once again. Hope you have a great day too!